# Wordpress site stuck in maintenance mode

Tags: wordpress

I can't figure out why my wp site is stuck in maintenance mode. I made no update and there's no .maintenance file. I can't even access to admin. 
Has anyone encountered similar issue?

Comment: If there is no .maintenacne file try disabling the plugins to see if that helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that by default `.maintenance` will be hidden, so if you are on *nix use `ls -la` to view it.

Comment: I hope this help. 1. Using FTP client software, I duplicated the .htaccess file and renamed it ".maintenance" I did this in my local file directory.

2. Upload the new ".maintenance" file to your root WP directory (or the one with wp-config.php as other posts mention)

3. Delete the ".maintenance" file source from this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-to-try-if-you-cant-find-the-maintenance-file-after-an-update

Comment: I'm going crazy. I've try each of your solutions and I've even reinstalled the website. I did not mentioned that the maintenance page seems to be a custom one with my client's company info. I've never set-up such a page. No .htaccess redirection, no domain redirection, no maintenance.html page I've checked everything. Is there a chance the site have been hacked?

Answer (score 3):

Try renaming the plugins/ folder to _plugins/ and see if you can access your website, if you can, rename the plugins folder to plugins/. Try disabling every plugin and re-enabling the plugin until your site breaks again to find the culprit.

If you can't access your website after renaming the plugins folder, disable your theme (by renaming the folder).

These are the common troubleshooting steps, if you provide more details, I will be able to help you more :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that.

Comment: Thank you. It did work. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, it was a domain redirection error. The url pointed to a folder with a default index.html.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem in 2017, I fixed it by going to my /wp-content/endurance-page-cache and deleting two files called _index.html and a_index.html (to be safe, I would download these first so that if this ISN'T the issue you can still recover them). This is what my domain was redirecting to.

Before I figured it out, I deactivated the WP Maintenance Mode plugin, looked through the directory for a .maintenance file (which I didn't find even after showing hidden files), and completely deleted the plugin. So hopefully if anyone is having this issue, this will work for you!